How to implement reverse Proxy For Oracle Databases
I have bunch of API servers that connects to single database node by configuring connection details  of it inside property file of api servers. Now let's imagine that I have 10 database nodes then what I have to do is to add 10 configuration for all databases in the properties file or segregate my api servers in such a way that some of them connects to database nodes 1 to 3, some connects to 4-6, 3 to 9 and so on if database nodes increases in future.
But, I want to offload this responsibility of knowing database topology from api servers to a different component of the system(say a Database reverse proxy). By doing so our api servers will have no need to be aware of the ip/port/servicename etc of different database nodes, they will connect to the database proxy and the database proxy will route the query to appropriate database node.
Below are some of the suggestions, but I have no idea which one to go for as oracle don't have any inbuilt feature to implement the use case

NGINX
Oracle CMAN(Oracle Connection Manager)
HA Proxy
Oracle RAC
Oracle Net Services (SQL*Net)

So, my question is which option to go for and why? How the queries will look like inside a jpa repository if any of above solution is implemented?
Till now I've tried nothing, as I don't know how to implement any of the mentioned approaches.

With RAC your clients can just transparently connect to the SCAN instead of a specific node...

Oracle JDBC drivers have some of those capabilities built in them. You can specify multiple hostnames and a service name. JDBS driver will seamlessly connect to hostname, where a service is up(advertised). Moreover you can also use LDAP for resolving database connection string or just pure DNS. You can have several A records(IP addresses) for single hostname.

If you are not already running RAC, then if you have Enterprise Edition I would recommend using Connection Manager. That said, your app servers will still need to identify IP/hostname, port, and service name no matter what. All any of these options will do for you is potentially reduce the number of addresses involved.

Also note that Nginx is an http/https proxy, not an Oracle TNS proxy. No idea what is even meant by "HA Proxy" or SQL Net. SQL Net is the entire TNS networking protocol for Oracle, not a proxy technology.

If you have Oracle Internet Directory you could possibly store your connection info in a single LDAP location and have clients look it up. Is that more what you're looking for?
